# 3 Brushless 40v Ryobi Motors with factory controllers; 4 12v 149Ah batteries in series for RC mower

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

First off I would like to say I am not a electrical engineer and know little to nothing as to what I need help with.

I have 3 40v Ryobi push-mower motors with controller off eBay:
[image]

Long Story short I get them to the house and try to get some life out of these suckers before moving to the next phase of my build; here’s what I’ve tried so far:

1. Watched this video on YouTube to bypass safety functions of the controller; so I could hookup the ground and power to 12v style car battery: https://youtu.be/Fnw7ciR_84E the main difference is the guy in the video is using an actual Ryobi battery…
2. Tried running the motor off of 12v style car battery (lead acid) ~ no luck
3. Ran 2 of the batteries in series @ 24v ~ no luck..
4. Tried 2 of the 3 motors in the same way ~ no luck..

What I havent tried is running 4 of the 12v batteries in series @ 48v; does anyone know anything about these batteries and controllers?

I plan on trying to run the 4 batteries in series tonight @ 48v to see if I havent been applying enough voltage to the controller.

Here is the wiring diagram of the Ryobi push motor I found online:
[image]

Comment: (Batteries are rated by Ah (Ampere-hours) rather than atto-Henry (aH).)

Comment: Please check [topics welcome at EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [topics welcome at DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If the motors are rated for 40 V operation, you should connect ONE motor to three of your batteries in series for 36 volts.  If that works, you can connect the other motors in parallel.

Comment: Either UVLO in the driver from too low voltage or the driver needs to handshake with the BMS in the battery.